# AIR published program does not display or work correctly

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have finished my Adobe AIR program and published it, but the installed program does not work correctly. Some objects load properly, but others do not.

Specifically I have around 20 images that line up together at Y:459 so the Y value is set in a loop before they are pushed into an array. The x value is then set by referencing their positions in the array. The images all appear at position 0 on the X axis.

Is there something I don't know about special considerations for arrays in AIR?
Other problems with the program may also be related to arrays; does anybody have an idea why?

The program functions correctly in Flash when tested so I don't understand why there is a problem in AIR. I have done some troubleshooting and updated AIR to version 15.0.0.356.

I tried to find some way to see error messages from the running program so I can see why it is failing, but have had no luck.

Many thanks for your advice.

EDIT
Thanks so much for your responses.
The first screenshot is the program tested from Flash and shows four images lined up at Y:459 and different X positions that are set separately.
http://i60.tinypic.com/r8f0gw.png

The second screenshot is the published, installed program that shows the four images that are lined up at Y:459, but they are all at X:0.
http://i58.tinypic.com/1z58dmv.png

I loop through an array of loaders, making a bitmap out of each, applying smoothing, adding to a movieclip so that they can be resized with my own :Image class, before they are pushed into 'lightImgs' array. Since they all need to be Y:459, I've done this in the loop and then changed the X positions outside the loop (you can see the first four images X positions being set)

```
lightImgs = new Array ();
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 21; i++){
            trace (i);
            var bmp:Bitmap = Bitmap (lightImages[i].content);
            bmp.smoothing = true;
            var tempMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip ();
            tempMC.addChild (bmp);
            var p:Point = new Point (150, 150);
            var tempImg:Image = new Image (tempMC, p);
            tempMC.x -= tempMC.width/2;
            tempMC.y -= tempMC.height/2;

            lightImgs.push (tempImg);
            tempImg.y = 459;
            addChild (tempImg);
            trace ('x ' + tempImg.x + ' y ' + tempImg.y);
        }

        lightImgs[0].x = 110;
        lightImgs[1].x = 270;
        lightImgs[2].x = 430;
        lightImgs[3].x = 590;
```

P.S please excuse me if this is not 'the way', I'm not a professional and learn as I go. I'm very interested to know why this works when tested but not when published :-s. Thanks!
P.P.S I apologise that I don't have enough rep to post images directly.

Comment: It would help to see your code.

Comment: picture is worth 1000 words:) show how it looks when tested from flash and how it looks standalone. Also code as @Craig mention would help.

Comment: Thank you. I have added code and links to images.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are just lists of data.  The issue will placement on the page is going to be related to the X position that you are assigning the image.   image.x = ?  If you loaded all of the with the same X or you haven't set the X location.  Then they will all stack on top of each other.  The other possibility is that your not taking into account the actual width of the image when you set the X value.  It is hard to diagnose the issue without a code example.  Also, there is no way to see an error from a running example unless you are checking for errors, or logging certain events.  If everything is showing up on screen, then the application thinks that everything is running properly.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have added a code example above.

Comment: On the last line in the if statement before you call the trace statement.  You have addChild(tempImg) what are you adding the tempImg too?  When you call addChild that is going to add it to the parent container.  A plain addChild can default to adding it to the stage.  If this is happening then it will be placing on the screen at the time that you call addChild.  A good suggestion is to use the syntax parent.addChild().  This helps to make sure you are adding the child to the proper parent container.